# how to pass custom data into KVKCalendarView

Tags: swift

Here is calendar view declaration

```
if let index = calendarVw.subviews.firstIndex(where: { $0.tag == 5005 }) {
    self.calendarVw.subviews[index].removeFromSuperview()
}
kvkCalendarView = KVKCalendarView(frame: self.calendarVw.bounds)
kvkCalendarView?.tag = 5005
kvkCalendarView?.dataSource = self
kvkCalendarView?.set(type: .week)
if kvkCalendarView != nil {
    calendarVw.addSubview(kvkCalendarView!)
}

var customEvent = Event(ID: "123")
customEvent.start = Date()
if let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 5, to: Date()) {
    customEvent.end = futureDate
}
customEvent.isAllDay = false
self.event = event
```

Comment: Please formulate a proper question in the body of the question, what are you trying to do and what is the problem that is stopping you.